# OpenCL/GL write_imagef causes performance issues

Tags: c++, opengl, interop, textures, opencl

I wrote a little raycaster in OpenCL with OpenGL interop and it didn't perform that well. The reason not being the calculations, but the call to `write_imagef`. The program runs at about 66fps when drawing to the OpenGL texture and at about 2900fps without. Are there any known reasons for this? I'm using the latest NVIDIA drivers and I doubt it's about my card, since it is quite a decent one (GTX 750TI). I call the method twice (I know, the first isn't actually necessary) one time to clear the screen:

```
write_imagef(screen, coords, colours[0]/*white*/);
```

and one time to draw the rendered pixel (if any objects intersect with it)

```
write_imagef(screen, coords, colour)
```

The first call to the function decreases the fps to around 2800, the second call alone to 66fps and both combined still result in 66fps.
I literally don't have the slightes idea about why this is happening.

Comment: Can you prove it's still doing the computations if you don't output to anywhere?  The driver could see that you aren't meaningfully consuming the output and simply...do nothing.  Which is usually pretty fast, as one might expect :)

Comment: I tested it. Writing the r value of the colour to a float array dropped the fps down to 66 aswell. However, putting in a random value (0.1)  had the same effect. Doing something like "float a = 0.1f;" didn't cause the behaviour. So I'm assuming OpenCL is maby doewnloading the texture (or float array in the test case) to the host, which takes some time. Can't explain it otherwise. But thanks alot for your suggestion. Really helped so far!

Comment: @genpfault is correct; since when you do neither your kernel has no output, the compiler optimized it away, perhaps to nothing at all. How big is this image you are writing to, and what is your global work size? 66 fps seems slow, unless you have a fairly low power GPU.

Comment: it was actually the compiler. It turned out that my raycasting algorithm was not efficient at all, however without writing to the image, the compiler removed this section